# How can I always default to the first tab of sub-navigation when changing the top navigation in Svelte component?

Tags: navigation, svelte, store

I have a Svelte app with a couple of components. One is for the main navigation of the page (Landing.svelte), and one is for sub-navigation (LandingSubNav.svelte). When you click on the different top nav options, different sets of sub-nav items appear.

It works fine. However, I'd like when changing the top nav, to always default to the first sub-nav item. I thought I could set this by specifying it in the on click event (code below is from Landing.svelte), but it's not working. Any help much appreciated.

```
    <nav id="navigation" />
    <div id="aspects">
      <button
        class="button statewide"
        on:click={() => {
          handleClick("statewide");
          $_tabSelect = "statewide";
          $_subTabSelect = 1;
```

The full app and code is [on Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-sun-r73wtu?file=/Landing.svelte:703-897).

Comment: In addition to `activeTabValue` which holds the value for the currently selected tab, you might need an additional variable to hold the value of the currently selected sub tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a new reactive statement in `LandingSubNav.svelte` that depends on `tabSelect` that resets `activeTabValue` to 1 when it changes:

```html
<script>
  import { _tabSelect, _subnavitems, _subTabSelect } from "./tab-store";

  // ...

  $: {
    tabSelect;
    activeTabValue = 1;
  }
</script>
```